# What is a proper question that is on topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

I encountered a problem with a host provider that they were unable to fix.  I'm not new to system administration, however this system was not under my control so I thought I ask if anyone had experience with this issue.  However my question was put on hold and I'm not sure why: [Sending email via php generates exim error after cPanel upgrade](https://serverfault.com/questions/563445/sending-email-via-php-generates-exim-error-after-cpanel-upgrade)

After consulting with the cPanel group I found the solution and would normally post it as an answer but my question is on hold.  Is this type of question not on topic for serverfault?  Should I have asked somewhere else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I closed the question, so it's only fair that I weigh in.

The distinction here is not that cPanel is off-topic *per se*; good questions involving cPanel are certainly possible. The distinction we make is whether the question involves *administering the system* as opposed to *being an end user of the system*.

Your *original* question read as though you were an *end user* of the system, thus it would not be answerable here. End user questions should be directed to the hosting provider, cPanel support, etc.

However, your updates are applicable to cPanel *administrators*, so I've reopened the question so that you may post them as an answer.

Answer (score 9):

[Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

cPanel and other panels are generally off-topic: use of those panels isn't really professional systems administration, though setting up the cPanel environment itself may be. cPanel also tends to be the *cause* of problems, rather than the solution, which is why most professionals avoid using it.

Comment: I regret only that I have but one upvote to give for this question.