# Why should questions about interactions between my server and bots off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, off-topic

I understand that this site has an established history of [prejudice ()](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels#comment17367_8055) towards questions about shared hostings or control panels. However, I still can't see how these questions ([1](https://serverfault.com/q/979938/536315), [2](https://serverfault.com/q/980012/536315)) not comply with the requirements in the [on-topic page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Those questions don't mention any control panel, using only commands to interact with the server, and asking about the communication between my server and bots. Since they aren't even about the interaction between the client (me) and the server, I think whether I have root access to my server or not is irrelevant.

I ask these questions not just to solve my immediate problem, but also to learn more knowledge about webserver/sysadmin, so that I can navigate what's best for me in the future, and to be more efficient to communicate with an insider. In my opinion, these questions can only be asked from a servermaster mindset, not a webmaster mindset.

I think the position of the asker is not important. But the mindset of the asker is.

I can ask them elsewhere (Reddit, say), but I think the SE format is best suited for them. Webmasters SE may also welcome them, but given that they are asked from a perspective of a wannabe servermaster, I think it should belong here.

Perhaps I cannot help myself, but gaining more knowledge with give me a better position to discuss with the technician. He has no obligation to help me debug, but if I can show him the possible problem, then probably it will intrigues his curiosity and work with me. And even if it's not possible, questions asking on SE are not solely to help the OP, but also help others. The questions are closed in order to avoid spiral with me only, but for others who actually have root access, they might see them interesting.

What are the harms for me to ask this kind of question? What are the harms for you to accept this kind of question? Why are these questions should be off-topic rather than on?

Comment: I appreciate your desire to learn. However, the answer is quite obvious in the meta post [you linked yourself](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels?noredirect=1&lq=1). _While we will answer "beginner sysadmin" questions we are not a basic education site, nor is the Q&A format well suited for that kind of basic training._ If you want to learn to become a server administrator, start by learning in an environment where you actually have administrator privileges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't accept web panel question. This topic had been covered a lot in the past and wont change today.

> I think whether I have root access to my server or not is irrelevant.

To answer you on that, I could ask you in example, can you provide a wireshark from the server side to diagnose the error ?

I'am not a Linux admin, but the fact you don't have root block us to help you, and the fact you use a management tool on top of that make it harder to diagnose. We can be seen heartless there, but in fact if someone sell you a shared hosting, it's him that need to answer you or open a support case to the web control panel software. It's him that can do the support for you.

There is nothing wrong by wanting to learn. My point is more you could not mark a answer as answered, as everyone could answer you something that technically could be right, but we could never rule out the solution.

A note, linking to a comment that talk about prejudice is not fair for SF members as it's took outside of context. (it was a big debate at that time). We just don't take those questions anymore, and [webmaster](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) is there for those questions.

Comment: Perhaps I cannot help myself, but gaining more knowledge with give me a better position to discuss with the technician. He has no obligation to help me debug, but if I can show him the possible problem, then probably it will intrigues his curiosity and work with me. And even if it's not possible, questions asking on SE are not solely to help the OP, but also help others. The questions are closed in order to avoid spiral with me only, but for others who actually have root access, they might see them interesting.

Comment: @Ooker There is nothing wrong by wanting to learn. My point is more you could not mark a answer as answered, as everyone could answer you something that technically could be right, but we could never rule out the solution.

Comment: I think that nails it. Perhaps you may want to include that in your answer

Comment: If I ask about how to use software to detect the possible problem, would that be on-topic?

Comment: @Ooker I would start by asking on webmaster if you did install your certificate correctly inside your gui, as like I told in your question on my side I got a PR_ error inside firefox which block your site to open while Michael don't have that error.

Answer (score 7):

You appear to be operating under the misapprehension that questions are assessed in some isolated, sterile environment, free from any influence of the past communications of the asker.  This is an incorrect assumption.

While it's true that the questions, as written, do not include direct reference to a management control panel, the questions were closed, I surmise, on the expectation that an initial round of diagnosis would quickly reveal the presence -- and the limitations -- of the control panel software, based on the content of the previous questions you've asked.

As Yagmoth555 said, the first thing we're going to need is things like pcaps, and the exact server config, and the ability to tweak arbitrary configuration parameters, and debug logging -- much of which is likely to be impossible, or at least several layers of "how do I do that?" meta-question, given the environment in which you are operating.

Thus, in the interests of saving the valuable time of those people who would otherwise get sucked into the vortex, such questions are quickly and summarily closed before they can commence to spiral.

Comment: I agree with the first two paragraphs, and I agree that the last two ones apply to almost all the cases. However, I acknowledge my limitation and do want to learn, so if the comments just say something like "can you type this command and tell me what you see", then even though I can't do that, I still learn something. The conversation will not commence to spiral, because it will just stop there. I just want you to give me some keywords so I can gain some insight.

Comment: That is not how a Q&A site works, though.  If that is what you are looking for, your needs will be better served elsewhere.

Comment: can you explain more on how Q&A sites won't work like that? What could go wrong, if there is no spiral vortex?

Comment: Well, for starters, questions and extended discussion do not go in comments.

Comment: I think that policy is only to prevent off-topic conversations. If comments are used for clarification or more information, as the fade text in the comment box says, then there would be no problem

Comment: No, that is not the purpose of that policy.

Comment: An elaboration on why you don't think it is would be helpful

Comment: @Ooker The purpose of the Q&A site is to create a repository of knowledge about the subject the specific site is aimed at. Comments are fleeting and expected to be removed at a future date. As such if the comments contain the majority of the troubleshooting / actual content, the Q&A is losing value. Equally, if the answer is "do command x" and you can't do it, then the Q&A is a net loss, because it just becomes useless noise for future posters. Who might have a similar question without the arbitrary limitations of a control panel.

Comment: @Reaces My idea was that "do command X" would be useful for future visitors, because they can save a one question to ask. But in retrospect, I think the question cannot belong to them, but is forever stuck with my name. Therefore, even if it saves them times, then the solutions they find cannot give back to the question. I get it now. Thank you

Comment: @Ooker "Do command x" is not useful if you, the op, responded with "I cant use this command". It just leaves future visitors guessing. And not because they have an odd system, but because you did.

Comment: @Reaces in my [first comment](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9553/why-should-questions-about-interactions-between-my-server-and-bots-off-topic/9555?noredirect=1#comment22770_9555), I said that if I'm unable to do command X, then I'll just stop there, not replying with "I can't use X"